# authentication using Doorkeeper from client-side application without transmitting secrets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-oauth, doorkeeper

I'm trying to use Doorkeeper in a Ruby on Rails API app for authentication. From a client-side AngularJS app, I want to get an access token. Currently, this involves a GET request to /oauth/authorize, which gives me a code, then I POST that code along with a client_id and a secret to /oauth/token. I don't want to have to send the client ID and secret from my client-side app, since they're stored in plain-text in a JavaScript file. I would like to follow [this flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent) where `response_type` is `token`, not `code`, but I can't figure out how to do that with Doorkeeper. [Their wiki](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki#flows) examples all seem to involve POSTing the client ID and secret to /oauth/token.

Is Doorkeeper the right gem for this? How can I do Google OAuth2 from a client-side app, where no secrets are passed from client-side to the server?

**Edit:** looks like what I want is Implicit Grant, which [Doorkeeper supports](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Supported-Features). Now I just have to find out how to do that in my Rails app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No extra server-side configuration necessary.

When I created a new `Doorkeeper::Application` in my Rails app, the Doorkeeper interface gave me an Authorize link with `response_type=code` in it for that application.

I changed that to `response_type=token` and when I do a GET request to that, it responds immediately with `access_token` instead of `code`. The Authorize URL looks like `http://my-rails-doorkeeper-app/oauth/authorize?client_id=1234&redirect_uri=http://my-angularjs-app&response_type=token`.

**Update :**

This can only be applied when we also allow implicit grant for the grant flow.
By default, doorkeeper will allow its four kinds of flow (implicit grant, authorization grant, password, and client_credentials).

You can configure it in `initializer/doorkeeper.rb` if you don't want to let it happens since sometimes it can be dangerous.